# PHP curl регистрация на сайте через post

Tags: php, curl, https, регистрация

Пытаюсь автоматизировать регистрацию на сайте рхел'а в благих целях, но пока что ничего не получается. Ниже код. Какие ошибки я совершаю? Заранее спасибо.

P.S. В данной тематике совсем/вообще/хуже некуда новичок.

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors',1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  $agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
  $url = "https://www.redhat.com/wapps/ugc/register.html?_flowId=register-flow&_flowExecutionKey=e1s1";
  $postData = array("notificationCheksum"=>"",
                    "timeZoneOffset"=>3,
                    "userType"=>"B",
                    "user.login"=>"NewUserSCUK223",
                    "user.personalInfo.email"=>"carrrrrramba@extremail.ru",
                    "password"=>"P@ssw0rd",
                    "passwordConfirmation"=>"P@ssw0rd",
                    "user.personalInfo.company"=>"MyCompani01",
                    "user.personalInfo.title"=>"MyCompany01Title",
                    "user.personalInfo.greeting"=>"Mr.",
                    "user.personalInfo.firstName"=>"JohnUser01",
                    "user.personalInfo.lastName"=>"BoltonUser01",
                    "site.address.countryCode"=>"RU",
                    "site.address.address1"=>"StFineh5",
                    "site.address.address2"=>"",
                    "site.address.address3"=>"",
                    "site.address.postalCode"=>"",
                    "site.address.city"=>"Moscow",
                    "site.address.county"=>"",
                    "site.address.state"=>"",
                    "user.personalINfo.phoneNumber"=>89991235768,
                    "user.personalINfo.faxNumber"=>"",
                    "_user.contactPermissions.allowEmailContact"=>"on",
                    "accepted"=>"true",
                    "_accepted"=>"on",
                    "redirect"=>"Submit",
                    "_eventId_sumbit"=>"",
                    "_flowExecutionKey"=>"e1s1");

  $stringpostData = http_build_query($postData);

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3');
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.redhat.com/en');

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $stringpostData);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));

  $result=curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);


?>
```

Comment: А какие ошибки заставили задать вопрос? Что есть "ничего не получается"?

Comment: Извините, что сразу не написал. Ошибок нет совсем. Но регистарция не проходит.